# Run query through set of dates

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I got 'periods' table looking like this

```
 _________________________________________
| startdate | enddate | personID | points |
| 01/01/15  | 01/15/15|     1    |   5    |
| 01/01/15  | 01/15/15|     2    |   5    |
| 01/01/15  | 01/15/15|     3    |   5    |
| 01/16/15  | 01/30/15|     4    |   5    |
| 02/01/15  | 02/15/15|     1    |   5    |
| 02/01/15  | 02/15/15|     5    |   5    |
```

Now in my view file, I got 2 select inputs where the user can choose an existing startdate and on the other, enddate. How is it possible when the user was personID #1?

```
If user whose UserID is 1, selected  
 startdate = 01/01/15  
 enddate = 02/15/15  
...it would display 10 as the total points  
If userID 1 selected  
 startdate = 02/01/15  
 enddate = 02/15/15  
...it would display 5 as the total points?
```

Comment: I've removed the tag from your title

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
function model_method($data) {
    $this->db->select("COUNT(points)");
    $this->db->from('periods');
    $this->db->where("personID", $data['userID']);
    $this->db->where("startDate >=", $data['startDate']);
    $this->db->or_where("enddate <=", $data['endDate']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```